Error reinstalling xampp after i got an issue

Translated Report (Full Report Below)
Process:               osx-x86_64 [3030]
Path:                  /private/var/folders/*/xampp-osx-8.2.4-0-installer.app/Contents/MacOS/osx-x86_64
Identifier:            osx-x86_64
Version:               ???
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        Exited process [3025]
User ID:               0
Date/Time:             2024-12-11 18:43:19.1808 +0100
OS Version:            macOS 15.1.1 (24B91)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     9.1 (22P1072)
Anonymous UUID:        08B1E16E-2D87-42D6-1DD6-6B32D21C347B
Time Awake Since Boot: 1500 seconds
System Integrity Protection: enabled
Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 6 Abort trap: 6
Terminating Process:   osx-x86_64 [3030]
Kern
External Modification Summary:
Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
task_for_pid: 0
thread_create: 0
thread_set_state: 0
Calls made by this process:
task_for_pid: 0
thread_create: 0
thread_set_state: 0
Calls made by all processes on this machine:
task_for_pid: 0
thread_create: 0
thread_set_state: 0
VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=708.2M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=708.2M(100%)
apple.main-thread"
I deleted all the files relating to xampp like those in the Application/Xampp folder

I recently did some updates on my Mac to the latest version 15.1.1 and i don't know i f it might be the cause but since then when i try running xampp it gives me the errors above and when i deleted everything and tried reinstalling i still get thesame error

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
